# React Router typescript Property 'redirectUrl' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to send state via history.push a part of url related to pagination to the login page.
But I don't know how to type it in Login, so the typescript will understand what exactly state contains.

The error that I'm receiving:

```sh
Property 'redirectUrl' does not exist on type '{}'
```

```js
if (!isAuthorized) {
   history.push({ pathname: AppRoute.login, state: { redirectUrl: 'page=2' } });

  return;
}
```

Login page

```js
const history = useHistory();
const redirectState = history?.location?.state;

if (isAuthorized) {
    history.push({ pathname: AppRoute.home, search: redirectState?.redirectUrl })

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you aren't calling `history.push()` correctly. It accepts a path and a state, as two separate arguments:

```
history.push(AppRoute.login, { redirectUrl: 'page=2' });
```

And then on the other side, you would type your `useLocation` call by passing it the it the state type you expect.

```
function LoginPage() {
  const location = useLocation<{ redirectUrl: string }>()
  console.log(location.state.redirectUrl) // typed as: { redirectUrl: string }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BvOAVwGckAJYBmaATwBp6mAZCGhQxgEAHZwAvnGy4CRdDAC0OOjCRQypNBPZwAgmDAII6pHAC8NOABsIAc2DiAXAQD09p+PzTS5cQ0oTHQLZAATYCIMAFUoWxpSODgiSOiYONs3dihnB1Ipf0w6cQwxSQBJcXCkAA8ABRQHJAAKAEpE5N1xfQALNg4oTis+FgGudv9k4tLRCTgJAHVekSQAN012zuS4fvYuADowRl6WoxMzDQOvZ15aVKikWPi3fDAmpEsAJl8pNoBuJJ+IFEGB0KCSAA8ACN1BxJBIAMK2YBoADWlmoSxWGg2UCkAD5BN5Ie5YTB4QSCv5SDMyvNic5Gs0ttQgd19PZhHNJNZGEhBNzypCIo9nrYCZMunoILYkNdHC0uSJygd2KsDg90pkOu53HAYJwwEhwnAUAw3KLtfEAMowVYFIA)